# Why am I getting a The installer was interrupted before xxx could be installed error when installing my ASP.Net Web application with installer?

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

I've got an ASP.Net application that I built a "Web Setup Project" for through VS 2010.
 The install package appears to have built correctly in Visual Studio.

I'm running into errors attempting to run the install package.
 I have to start by saying that I've built and deployed several WCF web services in this environment and they have all installed correctly.

Here is my environment:

---

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit
 IIS 7

I ran the installer with the logging facility and see the following errors:

> MSI (c) (10:80) [15:49:00:013]: Doing action: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE
>   Action 15:49:00: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE. 
>   Action start 15:49:00: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE.
>   MSI (c) (10:80) [15:49:00:015]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE' 
>   MSI (c) (10:80) [15:49:00:047]: Creating MSIHANDLE (13) of type 790542 for thread 38784
>   MSI (c) (10:80) [15:49:00:048]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\JohnB\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIBCE3.tmp, Entrypoint: SetTARGETSITE
>   MSI (c) (10!5C) [15:49:00:082]: Creating MSIHANDLE (14) of type 790531 for thread 35420
>   INFO   : [08/08/2014 15:49:00:082] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action is starting...
>   INFO   : [08/08/2014 15:49:00:082] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
>   ERROR  : [08/08/2014 15:49:00:085] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: FAILED:  -2147221164
>   ERROR  : [08/08/2014 15:49:00:085] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action failed with code: '340'
>   INFO   : [08/08/2014 15:49:00:087] [SetTARGETSITE                           ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '340'
>   MSI (c) (10!5C) [15:49:00:087]: Closing MSIHANDLE (14) of type 790531 for thread 35420
>   CustomAction WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
>   MSI (c) (10:80) [15:49:00:088]: Closing MSIHANDLE (13) of type 790542 for thread 38784
>   Action ended 15:49:00: WEBCA_SetTARGETSITE. Return value 3.
>   MSI (c) (10:80) [15:49:00:091]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm

I'm at a loss as to why the installation might be failing.
 I install by right clicking on "Setup.exe" and "Running as Administrator"

Of course time is sort of critical on this as we're attempting to deploy on Client machine by end of day today.
 Any thoughts/info would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
 JohnB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is Class not registered 0x80040154 so something about the IIS configuration may be amiss. I don't believe that VS setup projects were ever updated to deal with IIS7, so the issue may be that you need to set IIS6 compatibility in IIS.

Comment: I ended up dropping the panel and going Web Deployment packages for my WCF services and web applications.